# MVC3 Razor EF can't test in a strongly typed view for the existence of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a strongly typed MVC3 Razor view in which I want to display one actionlink or another, depending on whether or not a child object exists in the model.  I am unable to tell how to test for the object's existence, something I thought would be pretty straightforward.  I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 to generate the underlying relationships, database, and entities.

My POCO classes (much abbreviated):

```
public class Pet
{
    public int PetID { get; set; }

    public virtual InsurancePolicy InsurancePolicy { get; set; }
}

public class InsurancePolicy
{
    [ForeignKey(Pet)]
    public int InsurancePolicyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Pet Pet { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I thought I wanted to evaluate something like:

```
@foreach(var item in Model) 
{
    @if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.InsurancePolicy.InsuranceID.ToString()))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("action link to create new InsurancePolicy")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("action link to edit existing InsurancePolicy")
    }
}
```

Of course, if the Pet object has no associated InsurancePolicy yet, the conditional fails: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  I've been unable to find the equivalent of IsObject or any way to evaluate the nonexistence of the object without raising this error.

Can anyone point me to a way to make this work?

Comment: Directly inside the `foreach` body, you can't use `@`, since it's already a code block.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  However, the @ works when the child InsurancePolicy object exists, but fails when the child object doesn't exists.  So the @ if is working.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying.  Your code is a syntax error.  If it's actually inside an HTML tag, it's correct.

Comment: Interesting.  If I remove the @ from the if, it is displayed as text.  Maybe that's because I have a bunch of HTML preceding the conditional which I omitted in my example?

Comment: Exactly.  I thought so.  Your code as shown will not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for

```
if (item.InsurancePolicy == null)
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I KNEW it was something simple.  When I tried using null earlier, I forgot the equivalence operator in C# (new language for me).  Thanks so much!